# How can I find out the USB Bandwidth usage of device in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, bandwidth

I want to view the USB bandwidth usage of different devices on my Windows 10 laptop (1607).

I found [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772242%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article from Microsoft which advises to check in Device Manager, however the Advanced tab doesn't exist when I look at the properties of my USB Host Controller.

The controller name is "Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.0 (Microsoft)" so I thought I might need a less generic driver from Intel. But when I check the Intel site I can only find USB 3.0 drivers for Windows 7 and below.

Is there a way on Windows 10 to view the USB bandwidth usage of individual devices?